# Replace Special Characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i want to replace escape character(\)in the  path to single \ in js

```
\\cpmp1\D$\\ABC\\XYZ
```

i tried

```
console.log(s.replace(/.\\\\/g, '\\'));
```

but it does not do any replace ?Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4):

```
var replacedStr = s.replace(/\\+/g, '\\');
```

Comment: will this script replace all occurrences of \\ with \ ?

Comment: This will replace single backslashes followed by a "+" character with just a backslash.

Comment: `'\\cpmp1\D$\\ABC\\XYZ'.replace(/\\+/g, '\\') --->
"\cpmp1D$\ABC\XYZ"`

Comment: @Pointy oopsss... fixed that :)

Comment: It is also more efficient than `s.replace(/\\\\/g, '\\')` for what it's worth

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the ".", but otherwise that'll work.

```
console.log(s.replace(/\\\\/g, '\\'));
```

If it seems to be doing something incorrectly, then I suggest that your method of testing it may have a problem.

*edit* — Note that to test this with the suggested original string, it's necessary to double the backslashes:

```
var s = "\\\\cpmp1\\D$\\\\ABC\\\\XYZ";
```